# Android Pay Style Button not coming its Display Google wallet Style button

Tags: android, android-pay

I integrated Android pay using developer reference: https://developers.google.com/android-pay
But in UI of buy button i got old google wallet style button like :--[image]

I want android pay style button like :--[image]

I used **SupportWalletFragment** for this.
below is my wallet fragment style:

```
WalletFragmentStyle walletFragmentStyle = new WalletFragmentStyle()
                .setBuyButtonText(BuyButtonText.BUY_WITH_GOOGLE)
                .setBuyButtonWidth(Dimension.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: Android Pay hasn't launched yet. From what I remember the iconography will change when Android Pay Launches

Comment: Ya may be but they give  tutorial  on their website and in that they uses classes from new google play service 7.5.0.I copied from it But still i didn’t got UI like android pay...

Comment: I am also interested in how to get the Buy with Android Pay logos as well.

Answer (score 3):

The situation is the same the button is still the old google wallet style.
This is just a **hack** but if you really need it you can try this:

Create the wallet fragment in a normal way but hide it.
Create your custom button to look like Android Pay' one.

When the user    clicks your custom button you can click manually the    hidden    android pay button like this. (When the fragment has been created of    course).

```
if (walletFragment != null && walletFragment.getView() != null &&
                        ((FrameLayout) walletFragment.getView()).getChildCount() > 0) {
                    ((FrameLayout) walletFragment.getView()).getChildAt(0)
                            .callOnClick();
                }
```